# in toggle function the data() or attr('data-menu') not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I create a simple function to toggle the menus (there are two, one on the left and one on the right).

If I toggle first time, everything work.

If I toggle second time (close the button) it doesn't find the data-menu attribute. I don't understand why first it work, second not?

```
$('.dots-menu').toggle(
    function() {
      console.log( $(this).data('menu') )
      $( this ).children().addClass( "on" );
      $( '#dot-menu-event').addClass('open');
    }, function() {
      $( this ).children().removeClass( "on" );
      $( '#dot-menu-event').removeClass('open');
    }
  );
```

This is my HTML code

```
<div data-menu="event" class="dots-menu header absolute xbg-red-500 z-50 left-0 p-6">
            <button class="dots outline-none focus:outline-none"><span></span></button>
```

when i print my `$(this)` I get actually the div with the `data-menu="event"`.

```
<div data-menu=​"event" class=​"dots-menu header absolute xbg-red-500 z-50 left-0 p-6">​…​</div>​
```

Why JQuery not find the data-menu again?How I can solve this issue?

Comment: jQuery's `.toggle()` event method that alternated between two passed functions was [removed waaay back in 1.9](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Comment: The div shoud be define the id and the selector cslled by id with calss                                  <div id="event" data-menu="event" class="dots-menu header absolute xbg-red-500 z-50 left-0 p-6">
            <button class="dots outline-none focus:outline-none"><span></span></button>

the selector should be 
$( '#event .dot-menu').addClass('open');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery toggle() method was removed in version 1.9. So you can try the following alternative method I wrote. This should work exactly same.

```
$.fn.toggleIt = function() {     
   var _args = arguments, i = 0;    
   $(this).click(function() {
      i = (i == _args.length) ? 0: i;
     _args[i++].call(this);
   });
};
```

Here is an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.toggleIt = function() {    
    var _args = arguments, i = 0;    
    $(this).click(function() {
        i = (i == _args.length) ? 0: i;
        _args[i++].call(this);
    });
  };
  
  $("p").toggleIt(
    function(){ $(this).css({"color": "red"});},
    function(){ $(this).css({"color": "blue"});},
    function(){ $(this).css({"color": "green"});
  });
  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p style="font-size:40px">Click me.</p>

<div><b>Note:</b> Click to toggle between colors </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
$(document).on('toggle', '.dots-menu', function() {
        console.log( $(this).data('menu') )
        $( this ).children().addClass( "on" );
        $( '#dot-menu-event').addClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $( this ).children().removeClass( "on" );
        $( '#dot-menu-event').removeClass('open');
    }
);
```